# Prove that $\int_0^b x^3 dx = \frac{b^4}{4}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

The problem is as below:

> $\textbf{Problem 1}$ Prove that $\int_0^b x^3 dx = \dfrac{b^4}{4}$  by
> considering partitions into $n$ equal subintervals, using the  formula
> for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3$ which was found in problem 2-6.    This problem
> requries only a straightforwad imitation of calculations in the text,
> but you should write it as a formal proof to make certain that all the
> fine points of the argument are clear.

I'm using the 4th Ed. of Calculus by Michael Spivak. I'm looking for some criticism on my proof-writing. Here is my solution:

We consider the interval $[0,b]$ of the function $f(x) = x^3$.
We use lower and upper sums in our proof. First, let $P = \{t_0, \dots, t_n\}$ be a partition of $[0,b]$.

Suppose that these partitions divide $[0,b]$ into $n$ equal
subintervals. Then, the length of each subinterval is $\dfrac{b}{n}$.

Specifically, we have that $t_0 = 0, t_1 = \dfrac{b}{n}, t_2 = \dfrac{2b}{n}$. So, each partition $t_i = \dfrac{ib}{n}$. So, we define
$$
 m_i = t_{i-1}^3 \quad M_i = t_i^3
$$
so we have that
$$
 L(f, P) = \sum_{i=1}^n t_{i-1}^3 \dfrac{b}{n}
$$
and specifically,
$$
 L(f, P) = \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{(i-1)^3b^3}{n^3} \cdot \dfrac{b}{n}
$$
Moreover,
$$
 L(f, P) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j^3 \cdot \dfrac{b^4}{n^4}
$$
Which simplifies to:
$$
 L(f, P) = (\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2})^2 \cdot \dfrac{b^4}{n^4}
$$
The last steps:
\begin{align*}
 L(f, P) &= (\dfrac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4}) \cdot \dfrac{b^4}{n^4}
 \\&= \dfrac{(n-1)^2}{4} \cdot \dfrac{b^4}{n^2}
 \\&= \dfrac{(n-1)^2}{n^2} \cdot \dfrac{b^4}{4}
\end{align*}

The process for the upper sum is similar, we take the same partition:
\begin{align*}
 U(f, P) &= \sum_{i=1}^n (\dfrac{ib}{n})^3 \cdot \dfrac{b}{n}
  \\&= \sum_i^n i^3 \cdot \dfrac{b^4}{n^4}
  \\&= \dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} \cdot \dfrac{b^4}{n^4}
  \\&= \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{n^2} \cdot \dfrac{b^4}{4}
\end{align*}

Now, it is clear that $L(f, P) \leq \dfrac{b^4}{4} \leq U(f, P)$ for all $P$ of equal partition width.
By choosing $n$ sufficiently large, we can make $U(f, P_n) - L(f, P_n)$ as
small as desired where $n$ is the number of sub-intervals. Taking the limits of both sides to infinity, by squeeze
theorem, we see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} L(f, P_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} U(f, P_n)$ and so the integral is $\dfrac{b^4}{4}$ for the function $f(x) = x^3$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems perfect to me. I'd have just written that $U - L = 4/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.